# Factoring Non-Monic Quadratic Trinomials

Tags: quadratics, factoring

So I was going through an exercise on non-monic quadratic trinomials and the question asked me to factorise 2x^2 - 10x - 28.

So my working out was:

2x^2 - 10x - 28

x^2 - 10x - 56

(2x - 14) (2x + 4) / 2

(x - 7) (2x + 4)

Howeve,r my final answer was not listed as the correct one in the answer section. The correct answer was in fact 2(x + 2)(x − 7). Which of the answers would be considered "fully factored". I would have though the form that involves only the terms within the brackets is preferential however, it appears I may be wrong.

Comment: 1) Steps 2 and 3 are not necessary and are wrong. 2) After the last step, do a factorization by taking the common factor 2 out to get the required. 3) The most efficient method is to take the common factor 2 out right at the very beginning (so that the large numbers are significantly reduced)..

Answer (score 1):

Factorization can be seen as two different techniques, depending on the structure of the polynomial.

The monic - univariate polynomial having a non-zero coefficient with the highest term having the coefficient $1$.

The not monic polynomial is simply a polynomial that isn't monic.

So in your own case where you have the expression to be factorized: 
$2x^2−10x−28$

**Step 1**: 
This is a non-monic multivariate polynomial and fan-out the coefficients and constants

- coefficients are $2$ (first term) and $-10$ (second term)
- constant is $-28$ (last term)

**Step 2**:

- You need to multiply the coefficient of the first term to the
  constant (the last term)
- This gives you the product of $2x^2 * -28 = -56x^2$

**Step 3**

- Now find the *two terms* by trial and errors that can replace the
  middle term $(-10x)$ when added together.
- In this case, the product $-56x^2$ is mathematically equivalent to the
  product of $-14x$ and $+4x$, implying that these terms could possibly
  replace the middle term $(-10x)$ when added together

**Step 4**

- Now take $-14x$ and $4x$ and replace this into the equation by factoring
  the terms as shown below
- > $2x^2 - 14x + 4x -28$
- > $2x(x -7) + 4(x -7)$ simplify and regroup the expression

**Step 5**

- Factoring by inspection then you have
- $(2x + 4)(x - 7)$
- Further, simplify the expression on the left through by factor of
  $2$
- $2(x + 2)(x - 7)$

Answer (score 0):

i solved it like this:

$2x^2-10x-28$

$a=2, b=-10, c=-28$

$ac=-56$ (factors of $ac$ include $-14$ and $4$)

$=2x^2-14x+4x-28$

$=2x(x-7)+2(x-7)$

$=(2x+2)(x-7)$

$=2(x+2)(x-7)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).